# ADO Query of Sheet With Long Name Results in Jet Error

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado, jet

*(a follow up to my question yesterday, **["ADO Reference to Excel Worksheet Ending in Period (“.”) Results in Jet Error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432104/ado-reference-to-excel-worksheet-ending-in-period-results-in-jet-error)**)*

I thought that an ADO query I was making against a sheet name ending with a period was throwing an error due to the period, but I believe that was a red herring. I ran into similar issues with another sheet with a long name and no periods. Shortening the name seems to solve the problem.

I found the following [reference on the limitations of Microsoft Access](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/access_specifications.html), the closest thing I could find to limitations of the Jet database engine used by ADO to query Excel. In this (unofficial) reference, it mentions a table name maximum length of 64 characters. In my experience, ADO doesn't seem to successfully query Excel sheets with names longer than 30 characters (note that Excel will allow a maximum of 31 characters for a sheet name).

Is there a reason that ADO would not be able to query a valid Excel sheet name of 31 characters?

Comment: There is an interesting discussion here: http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=193099

Answer (score 0):

There is no easily-found Microsoft documentation of this limitation, but the length limit for an Excel worksheet's name is 31, whether you edit it directly or try to interact via ADO.